# jQuery: text and disable it when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the text of a button and disable it once it has been clicked.

```html
<button id="btnResendVerificationEmail" class="btn btn-success">click text</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#btnResendVerificationEmail').click(function() {
    jQuery.post('clientarea.php', {
      'token': '{$token}',
      'action': 'resendVerificationEmail'
    }).done(function(data) {
      jQuery('#btnResendVerificationEmail').prop('disabled', true).text('done text');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: "show text and disabled" works. But it is never called. You have a problem with your jQuery post

Comment: Check out this answer, it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/8820742

Comment: I know shows text and disabled when done , I want show also when click another text

Comment: because called takes 3 minutes

Comment: @Saeed' please clarify your issue or question. The posted code appears to work as expected.

Comment: @Twisty Now code working (click >> waiting called >> show text done and disabled)  I want to working like this ( click >> show waiting text and disabled >> after called show text done and disabled)

Comment: @Saeed' So you want when the User clicks the button, the HTTP Post starts; text to indicate that the script is loading something; "done" is triggered; and then change text to indicate it is done. Is this correct?

Comment: @Twisty Yes Yes

Comment: @Twisty It works as I requested but the verification email is not sent.

Comment: @Saeed' that would be entirely outside the scope of this question. I would investigate further, check logs, enable debugging, and if needed post a new PHP question.

Comment: @Twisty Old code The message is sent successfully.
The new code does not send the message, but text appears as I want

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `jQuery.ajax()` where you can make use of `beforeSend` callback. This allows you to modify the Button before the HTTP Post. Then you can modify it again in `success` callback.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var int;
  var c = 0;

  function showLoading(obj) {
    int = setInterval(function() {
      var t = "Load";
      switch (c % 3) {
        case 0:
          t += "...";
          break;
        case 1:
          t += "..";
          break;
        case 2:
          t += ".";
          break;
      }
      c++;
      obj.html(t);
    }, 200);
  }

  $('#btnResendVerificationEmail').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
      data: {
        token: "token-1234",
        action: "resendVerficiationEmail"
      },
      method: "POST",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#btnResendVerificationEmail').prop("disabled", true);
        showLoading($('#btnResendVerificationEmail'));
      },
      success: function(data) {
        clearInterval(int);
        $('#btnResendVerificationEmail').html("Done");
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnResendVerificationEmail" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
```

Read More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Old code The message is sent successfully. The new code does not send the message, but text appears as I want